# CSS Animations not Running on IOS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have the following CSS animations, that all work flawlessly on Desktop browsers (even when the window is resized).

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0e1624;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    animation: enable-scroll 0.1s forwards;
    color: white;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@keyframes enable-scroll {
    to {
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}

#page-loader {
    animation: page-loaded 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes page-loaded {
    to {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

As I said, on desktop, more or less regardless of browser, it runs flawlessly. However, whenever I try and open the site on my phone, the animations don't run and as such, none of the content is shown.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you inspected the browser for any errors? Also, are these animations not running on Android as well or only iOS?

Comment: @tomerpacific I don't have any android devices to check, how can I inspect safari for errors?

Comment: You can't animate the `display` property (it will change, but there won't be any animation) are you sure you need keyframes for this?

Comment: `@-webkit-keyframes` [hasn't been necessary for almost a decade now](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40keyframes). Please stop using superfluous CSS vendor prefixes.

Comment: Where is your `animation:` property? Showing us `@keyframes` alone doesn't help us diagnose the problem at all.

Comment: @Dai thank you for letting me know. I've now removed this from my code. I've also edited my question to show my `animation:` properties.

Comment: @DBS I'm using an animation to save me having to add more JS to the initial page when  I just need to change a property (without animation) after x amount of seconds.

Comment: @Dai it seems to work perfectly fine on desktop though? You can see what I mean at the beta page. https://beta.beenhamow.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I can only go off your post, so I'm assuming you are manually resizing the window which doesn't fully represent responsiveness. You need to to use your dev tools for whatever browser you use and from there you can select specific devices to test on.

For Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, and Mozilla Firefox:
Windows: Press F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I
macOS: Press Cmd + Option + I

For Safari on macOS:
macOS: Press Cmd + Option + I

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my lack of specificity. That is the process that I was using to troubleshoot on my laptop using chrome.